# Create view with fields from another table as column headers

Tags: t-sql

I've got two tables that I'd like to combine into a view. The first table contains the structure:

**Template Table**

```
componentID | title
======================
1000        | blue
1001        | red
1002        | orange
```

The second table contains the actual data that will be stored, and the columns reference the ID of the first table:

**Data Table**

```
id | field1000 | field1001 | field1002
======================================
1  | navy      | ruby      | vermilion
2  | midnight  | crimson   | amber
```

What I'd like to get as a result in a view:

**Combined Table/View?**

```
id | blue     | red     | orange
=================================
1  | navy     | ruby    | vermilion
2  | midnight | crimson | amber
```

Is this possible? I've been trying to get it to work with pivot tables, but I'm getting hung up on how to use the titles as the columns for the data.

Comment: read up on cursors, they can be used to achieve this

Comment: is that the best or only way to achieve the results i'm looking for?

Comment: it's not the only way, as you can see below, but imo they are very useful. I'm thinking more about dynamic queries that you won't know all the columns for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I went a bit overboard with this one but this will do what you want. This procedure will combine all fields with the proper data table columns, and does not need to know nor care how many columns there are in the data tables.

It does not use cursors, but due to the possibility of many template tables, it does use Dynamic SQL to generate the `Select` statement for the final return.

Only caveat is it's not a `View`, it's a `stored procedure`, because it allows to pass the variable for the data table you want to ultimately select from.

**The assumptions:**

1. The template table is static
2. There is one template table for all data tables
3. All fields in any data tables must be unique *
4. All data tables have a PK/identity field with the word 'id' in it that must be ignored
5. All fields in the data tables have a corresponding title in the template table
6. All fields in the data table are prefixed with the word 'field' and all of the reference ID's in the template table correspond to those field names with 'field' removed, based on your example

*- It can of course be improved by modifying the template table schema to also have a field for the data table that the field title belongs to, for example, which would remove this assumption #3.

**The process:**

- First we need a mapping of the field names, reference IDs, and column titles. We do this with a `table variable` and get our info from `syscolumns`. Then, we update our temp table to get the titles from the `TemplateTable table`.
- Then, we need to build a dynamic `Select` list from the DataTable (which is a parameter in the SP and therefore requires some dynamic SQL to execute). My preferred method of doing this is by having a bit column in my source table that I can update, something like 'IsCompleted', and then using a regular `While` loop to get through each row. Inside the While loop, all we do is grab the current "TitleReference" from our temporary table variable, and append to the select list the real field name from syscolumns (from first step above).
- Finally, we execute the dynamic SQL statement which has a `Select`, and when this is inside a `stored procedure` that is executed, the result is returned as the result of the `stored procedure`.

**The Full Working Code**

```
Create Procedure usp_CombineTables
(
    @DataTableName varchar(50)
)
As
    -- Test
    -- Exec usp_CombineTables 'DataTable'

    -- Set up our variables
    Declare @DataTableIdFieldName varchar(50),  -- The ID field of the data table, dynamic
            @IsCompleted bit,                   -- Used by While loop to know when to exit
            @CurrentTitleReference  int,        -- Used in While loop as the ID from TemplateTable that relates to the real data field name and the desired title 
            @CurrentDataFieldName varchar(50),  -- Used in While loop for the current actual field name in the data table
            @CurrentTitle varchar(50),          -- Used in While loop for the desired field name in the resulting table of the stored proc
            @DynamicSelectQuery varchar(2000)   -- Stores the SQL query that is dynamically built and executed for the final result; can increase value if needed

    -- Use table variable to correlate the datatable columns, titles, and references
    Declare @TitleReferences Table (
        TitleReference int,
        DataTableColumnName varchar(50),
        Title varchar(50),
        Completed bit default 0
    )

    -- Get the info from syscolumns about our datatable; assumes that all of the field names are prefixed with the word 'field' which needs to be removed
    Insert Into @TitleReferences ( 
        TitleReference,
        DataTableColumnName
    )
    Select 
        Replace(name, 'field', '') As TitleReference,
        name As DataTableColumnName
    From syscolumns 
    Where id = OBJECT_ID(@DataTableName)
        And name Not Like '%id%' -- assumes DataTable will always have a PK with 'id' in it, need to ignore/remove

    -- Get the titles -- assumes only one template table for all data tables; all data fields accross tables must be unique
    Update @TitleReferences
        Set Title = t.Title From TemplateTable As t
        Where TitleReference = t.ComponentID

    -- Get the ID field of the data table
    Set @DataTableIdFieldName = (
        Select name From syscolumns 
        Where id = OBJECT_ID(@DataTableName)
        And name Like '%id%')

    -- Build a dynamic SQL query to select from the datatable with the right column names
    Set @DynamicSelectQuery = 'Select ' + @DataTableIdFieldName + ', ' -- start with the ID
    Set @IsCompleted = 0
    While (@IsCompleted = 0)
        Begin
            -- Retrieve the field name and title from the current row based on title reference
            Set @CurrentTitleReference = (Select Top 1 TitleReference From @TitleReferences Where Completed = 0)
            Set @CurrentDataFieldName = (Select DataTableColumnName From @TitleReferences Where TitleReference = @CurrentTitleReference)
            Set @CurrentTitle = (Select Title From @TitleReferences Where TitleReference = @CurrentTitleReference)

            -- Append the next select field to the dynamic query
            Set @DynamicSelectQuery = @DynamicSelectQuery + 
                @CurrentDataFieldName + ' As ' + QuoteName(@CurrentTitle)

            -- Set up to move past current record in next iteration
            Update @TitleReferences Set Completed = 1 Where TitleReference = @CurrentTitleReference

            -- Exit loop or add comma for next field
            If (Select Count(Completed) From @TitleReferences Where Completed = 0) = 0
                Begin
                    Set @IsCompleted = 1    
                End
            Else
                Begin
                    -- Add comma to select field for next column
                    Set @DynamicSelectQuery = @DynamicSelectQuery + ','
                End
        End

    -- Now the column list is built, just add the table and exec
    Set @DynamicSelectQuery = @DynamicSelectQuery + 
        ' From ' + @DataTableName

    Exec(@DynamicSelectQuery)
```

**The Result**

[image: the result]

Hope this helps, it was fun writing it!

Comment: I ended up using this with a few adjustments: I changed the dynamic query to create or alter a view instead, and added another while loop to rename any duplicate columns to ensure the view doesn't fail. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

something on these lines

```
DECLARE @f0 VARCHAR(50)=(SELECT title FROM template WHERE componentID=1000)
DECLARE @f1 VARCHAR(50)=(SELECT title FROM template WHERE componentID=1001)
DECLARE @f2 VARCHAR(50)=(SELECT title FROM template WHERE componentID=1002)
@sql='SELECT field1000 AS ' + quotename(@f0)  + ' field1001 AS ' + quotename(@f1)  + ' field1002 AS ' + quotename(@f2) + ' FROM data'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: since the number of rows in the first template table can change it would be preferable (if possible) not to hard code the id numbers.